# Why does not mnt/sdcard/Android/data folder exist on my emulated devices?

Tags: android, eclipse, file-io, android-emulator, ddms

My app stores its private data in mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp folder. I see that many other apps have their folder there, it was a suggested location. 
I am testing my app on a 7" tablet running 4.0.3 Android version and it works; it is compiled against Api level 12 (Android 3.1). It issues a mkdir command with complete path (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+APP_DATA_FOLDER_PATH).

My question is about why I cannot see that folder on various emulated devices (with Eclipse DDMS view), and in fact my app fails to access those data after writing them (it writes a JSON text file). I get no error from mkdir call. 
Maybe emulated filesystem is read-only; but my emulated devices do have sdcard space. Maybe I should create Android and then data folders first? It is weird, I thought that folder was created by the system.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about your problem.  State the specific device or emulator on which you experience it, the full absolute path which is not working, the exact method you are using to access it, and the precise nature of the error received.

Comment: @Chris Stratton see my edit. I get no error when writing, and when it comes to read my app performs a check so no error again, just internal problems.

Comment: Have you created the folder?  Show the code which writes - perhaps it is not able to detect errors.  Also your path is not stated as an absolute one (with a leading slash) which could be a source of error.  Additionally, that may not be a valid path on all devices - you should be discovering the external storage path at runtime.  Finally, is your emulator configured with an image file to emulate the SD card?

Comment: @Chris Stratton see my complete re-editing of the question, thank you.

Comment: This is still not code which someone can look at to see possible errors or omissions.  And yes, you should verify that all folders in the hierarchy exist.

Answer (score 0):

"mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp" is the path that context.getCacheDir() returns, not for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), which should return /mnt/sdcard-ext/...